# Efficient traversal of a graph stored as a table in a relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, graph, graph-traversal

I have a table that represents graph data structure **with no circular dependencies** in an edge list representation as such:

```
 ________________
| id | from | to |
 ________________
| 1  |  3   |  4 |
| 2  |  3   |  5 |
| 4  |  5   |  7 |
 ________________
```

Is it possible to do a SQL query such that for a specific vertex `v`, retrieve the set of vertices `V` consisting of all connected vertices, both directly and indirectly?

E.g. `retrieve_all_connected_vertices(3)` will return the set `(4, 5, 7)`.

The approaches I am looking at are those that uses pure SQL statement supported by MySQL (stored procedures and the likes are out of options), or in combination with some kind of pseudo programming languages. I am not looking for a language specific implementation, although I will be using Scala for this particular purpose.

I am aware that we can just basically follow the link recursively until it reaches the very last vertices, however, I will be glad if there are some kind of optimizations that can be used in order to reduce either memory usage or algorithmic complexity.

Comment: MySQL does not support hierarchical queries or recursive queries.  Two options are:  use stored procedures or switch databases.

Comment: Wouldn't 3->4 and 4->3 be a circular dependency?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Your comment is the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

The plain query would be parametrized in code.

```
SELECT vertices.to FROM vertices WHERE vertices.from = ?
```

And you have to pass the vertex you want as input, where you'd need a Scala SQL connector that can pass parameters.

By the way, be careful with column names that could also be MySQL keywords.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; this query will only select the direct dependencies of `vertices.from`, not all recursive dependencies.